# Whether NOAA AVHRR NDVI V5 already remove cloud?

Tags: remote-sensing, ndvi, noaa

We want to use NOAA/CDR/AVHRR/NDVI/V5 datasets for analysis, but we are not sure if the NDVI already remove the cloud and cloud shadow or not?
Need we use 'QA' to remove the cloud and cloud shadow further?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Could you please provide a URL to the data you downloaded? Have you inspected the matadata?

Comment: yeah, of course. this is the URL: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NOAA_CDR_AVHRR_NDVI_V5

Comment: And this URL is about the algorithm description:https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/sds/cdr/CDRs/Normalized%20Difference%20Vegetation%20Index/AlgorithmDescription_01B-20b.pdf    This document has said the products will be generated for each cloud-free pixel, although we still could find negative values(which means cloud) on GEE inspector::https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=Examples:Datasets/NOAA_CDR_AVHRR_NDVI_V5